# Can't use Vue.js Data in Created ()

Tags: vue.js

I'm wondering if is it possible, how can I use `Vue.js` data in my Created() function.

I'll show some code so you can see why I say.

```
 data (){

        return {
            model: {},
            foo: 'boo'

        }

    },

    created (){

        const getModel = () => {
            const modelId = this.$route.params.id 
            axios.get('/api/model', { params: {modelId: modelId}})
                .then(res => {
                    this.model = res.data
                    this.boo = 'hello'

                    console.log(this.model)
                    console.log(this.foo)
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

        getModel()


        const init =  () =>{        
            console.log(this.model) 
            console.log(this.foo)  
        }

        init()
```

The first console.log(foo) returns 'hello'.
The second one (init) returns 'boo'.

Also the first console.log(this.model) is what I expect to get but once is out of the axios method it's like empty again all over the mounted function.

I've tried a lot of things but none of them worked, hope I get a solution... Thanks in advance!

Comment: so the error comes from this.getModel right?

Comment: That works fine, actually I get the model object in data but it's not available in created/mounted functions. It's only available in the html section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as JS functions are non-blocking - your axios call isn't done (model is still empty) when you call for init

1. Define `init` as components method
2. Call `this.init()` in `axios.get` callback

Comment: Wasn't necessary to define init as a method but was enough calling init() after .then in axios.get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the fact that in your `created` hook you're creating a function using the `function` keyword, which means your `init` function will have its own context(its own **this**).

A solution to this problem would be to use an **arrow function**.

```
    data () { return { foo: 'bar' } }
    created () {
        const init = () => {
            console.log(this.foo);
        }
       init(); // bar
    }
```

[More about arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)

### UPDATE

Actually, the issue stems from not awaiting for `getModel`. Because you are making a request, you first need to wait for the promise to resolve, and then use its resolved data in the code that depends on it.

The **async/await** version would be:

```
async created () {
  const getModel = async () => {
        const modelId = this.$route.params.id 
        try {
            const res = await axios.get('/api/model', { params: {modelId: modelId}})

            this.model = res.data
            this.boo = 'hello'
            console.log(this.model)
            console.log(this.foo)
        }  catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        } 

    }

   const init =  () =>{        
         console.log(this.model) 
         console.log(this.foo)  
    }

  // An async function always returns a promise
  await getModel();
  init();  
}
```

Comment: This is not even printing bar on the console btw

Comment: That's working with foo! Thanks, but not even working with model, it's empty... I have to say that in the html i'm getting the model name from the data which is supposed to be empty in the created method, I don't know how

Comment: Have you tried to await for this.getModel() and then call init()? I think you have to get the model first and then use it in your init function.

Comment: I'll edit so you can see how is it going right now, hopefully you can tell me how to put those async/awaits

Comment: Okey was enough calling init in axios method after .then